# How to show "slug" in admin column?

Tags: slug

```
    function my_school_taxonomy() {
        register_taxonomy(
            'schoolcategory',
            'school',
            array(
                'label' => __( '學校分類' ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'schoolcategory' ),
                'show_ui' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                )
            );
    }
```

[image]